# What is Massart Noise?

Tags: noise, pac-learning

One of best papers during NeurIPS 2019 - [Distribution-Independent PAC Learning of Halfspaces with Massart Noise](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/8722-distribution-independent-pac-learning-of-halfspaces-with-massart-noise) mentions **Massart Noise** in the title. What is this type of noise? How is it different from other known types of noise? I am looking for a relatively simple explanation as it is difficult to dive in the definition of the paper.

Comment: Isn't your question answered by Definition 1.1 of the paper?

Comment: It may well be but this definition is difficult to grasp for a person new to the field. Besides, the definitions in papers are written to impress not to explain.

Comment: Well then how about the next sentence after Definition 1.1?
Quote: "An equivalent formulation of the Massart model is the following: With probability 1−η , we have that y = f(x) , and with probability η the label y is controlled by an adversary".

Sounds impressive yet reasonable doesn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually explained in the text. Basically, it's any type of noise satisfying the condition that, when applied, there is still at least a margin of the size $\beta$ separating the class *probabilities*.

For example, $\beta=0.5$ in a binary setting means the least confident classification in the Massart-noisy data is `[75% A, 25% B]` or `[25% A, 75% B]`, and some label probabilities may go as high as, say, `[90% A, 10% B]` or even `[100% A, 0% B]` or vice versa.

Another way of looking at it is in terms of the noise probabilistically flipping the labels to incorrect values; then a Massart noise is such a function that does it with no more than $\frac{1-\beta}{2}$ probability.

Comment: Particularly the 2nd explanation is very easy to grasp. Thank you!